# \cite suddenly producing "Undefined control sequence"

Tags: bibtex

My document was compiling correctly, including bibliography (in same directory as .tex file).  Now all the citations are suddenly producing undefined control sequence errors.  Also, some errors of \@year@ doesn't match its definition errors, still for citations.

Looks like this:

```
\documentclass[jou,apacite]{apa6}
\usepackage{url}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-}
\title{foo}
\shorttitle{bar}
\author{me}
\affiliation{Uni}
\rightheader{APA style}
\leftheader{me}
\begin{document}
\maketitle  

Blabla~\cite{Author1979}.

\bibliography{BetterBibTex}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Check if the `bib` file has some error or some missing braces.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Bib file is good... produced by BetterBibTex; fixed format.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  Again, this was compiling correctly... suddenly stopped.

Comment: We're probably going to need a [MWEB (Minimal (non-)working example with Bibliography)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography) to be able to help you.

Comment: Do you get the same errors if you delete the generated files (`aux` etc.) and recompile?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is just about having to delete an `aux` file in order to fix things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cfr's comment provided the answer---deleting the generated files (aux etc.) and recompiling solved this.  Sometimes it's the simple things...

Comment: Deleting all temp files did not solve issue for me. Still puzzle why one second it was working and the next this happened.